# Need help figuring out how to loop through indice

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, indices

I am working on a project that revolves scraping a lot of data. I am working on a rather long script right now but running into a problem with my for loop.

I am trying to scrape information out of a 9 row table. I have tried to set up a for loop so that it scrapes the same information from each row. In order to access the first row, I split the table into a list. The first row starts with the third indice.

Here is my Code:

When I run it I get an, "AttributeError" at the line "Aa" is on. The error reads, "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

This doesn't happen when I feed that line of code individually into the console, I get the desired text. And when I take out the for loop I am able to scrape the first indaplaybox.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url ='Myurl/=' + page

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
boxes = page_soup.findAll("table",{"class":"TableTable tableBody"})
box = boxes[0]
playboxes = box.find_all('tr')
indaplaybox = playboxes[3]

filename = "QBS.csv"
f = open(filename, "a")

headers= "Aa, Ab, Ac, Ad\n"
f.write(headers)

for indaplaybox in playboxes:

    Aa = indaplaybox.find('td', attrs = {'style' : 'font-weight: bold;'}).text

    c = indaplaybox.find('td', attrs = {'class' : 'tablePlayName'})
    cl = c.text.split() 
    Ab = cl[0] + " " + cl[1]
    Ac = cl[2]
    Ad = indaplaybox.div.a.text



    print("Aa:" + Aa)
    print("Ab:" + Ab)
    print("Ac:" + Ac)
    print("Ad:" + Ad)


    with open (filename, "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(Aa + "," + Ab + "," + Ac.replace(",", "|") + "," + Ad + "\n")
f.close()
```

I want to loop through the playbox indices 3-11.

I am not well versed with indices, so tried to do something like:

```
p = [str(i) for i in range (3,12)] 
indaplaybox = playboxes[p]

for indaplaybox in playboxes:

    rest of code
```

But that doesn't work, because what is probably obvious to most is that list indices must be integers.

I could really use some help thinking through how to get this for loop running smoothly. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably because bsoup didn't find anything for your requested query. I think it returns `None` if it can't find anything.

Comment: First instinct is that `indaplaybox.find('td', attrs = {'style' : 'font-weight: bold;'})` is returning `None`, and you can't call `.text` on that. I see you may have duplicated some variable names; `indaplaybox = playboxes[3]`. If it were me, I'd remove or change that line to make sure that's not the issue, then `print(indaplaybox.find('td', attrs = {'style' : 'font-weight: bold;'}))` without calling `.text` and see what is returned

Comment: Thanks for the help y'all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

**Method 1:**

```
# p has all the values from playboxes at these indexes
p = [playboxes[i] for i in range(3,12)]

# now simple loop
for indaplaybox in p:
    ......
```

**Method 2:**

```
for indaplaybox in playboxes[3:12]:
    ....
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't you just taking values out of a list, adding them into a new list based on their indices in order, then iterating over the new list? You might as well just do `p=playboxes.copy()` and `for indiaplaybox in p[3:12]`...

Comment: @G.Anderson yes, you are right, that's easier infact. I'll add it.

Comment: Y'all are freaking great. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
p = [str(i) for i in range (3,12)] 
for i in p:
    indaplaybox = playboxes[i]
    ...
    rest of the code
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help :)